# How to know on which GPU tensorflow model is training on

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, gpu, tensorflow2.0

I have installed `tensorflow-gpu` to train my models on GPU and have confirmed the installation from below.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
tf.config.list_physical_devices()

#[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU'),
# PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
```

I started training an image classification model and I hope it runs on GPU automatically until and unless specified to run manually on a device. But while training the model I could see in my task manager that there were 2 GPU's and `Intel Graphics card` was GPU 0 and `NVIDIA GeForce GTX1660Ti` was GPU1. Does that mean tensorflow didn't detect my NVIDIA card or is it the actual GPU that was detected?

While training the model I could see that my NVIDIA GPU utilization was very low. Not sure on which device my model was trained.

[image]

Can someone clarify please.

Further version details. `tf.__version__ (2.6.0)`, `python 3.7`, `CUDA 11.4`, `cudnn 8.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to enable debug:

```
tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)
```

I think your Intel GPU is ignored by `tf.config.list_physical_devices()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can you confirm that Intel GPU is ignored?

Comment: Tensorflow uses CUDA which means only NVIDIA GPUs are supported.